# function to return the first possible substring containing all the elements of substring

Tags: python, string, substring

How can I modify the `myStr` function to return the first possible substring (traversing from left) containing all the elements of `str2`. For example: given `str1 = 'xBxxAxxCxxAxCxxBxxxAxCxBxxxAxxBxCx'` and `str2 = "ABC"`, the function should `return "BxxAxxC"`.

```
str1 = input("Enter the first string: ")
str2 = input("Enter the second string to check if the characters exist in the first string: ")

def myStr(str1, str2):
    
    if all(i in str1 for i in str2):
        return True
    else:     
        return False

myStr(str1, str2)
```

Comment: What does your current code do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'xBxxAxxCxxA'`? That starts earlier.

Comment: Why do you return True and False if you want to return a string?

Comment: When you write sample code for us, consider hard coding the data instead of letting us enter it. That is, write `str1 = 'xBxxAxxCxxAxCxxBxxxAxCxBxxxAxxBxCx'` and `str2 = "ABC"` instead of the first two `input()` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that left-most characters that are *not* in `str2` should be *excluded*, you could do the following:

- Create a set for the characters in `str2`
- Iterate the characters from `str1` and remove them from this set.
- Once the set is empty, you know that the condition is fulfilled.
- To exclude the left most characters, keep track which was the first index where there was a match with a character in the set.

```
def myStr(str1, str2):
    todo = set(str2)
    start = -1
    for i, ch in enumerate(str1):
        if not todo:
            return str1[start:i]
        if ch in todo:
            todo.discard(ch)
            if start < 0:
                start = i
```

Answer (score 1):

If str2 doesn't contain any duplicates letters, you can map its characters to their first positions in str1 and get the range between the minimum and maximum positions:

for example:

```
str1   = 'xBxxAxxCxxAxCxxBxxxAxCxBxxxAxxBxCx'
str2   = "ABC"

pos    = [str1.find(c) for c in str2]
result = str1[min(pos):max(pos)+1]

print(result) # BxxAxxC
```

*If not all characters of str2 are present in str1, this will produce an empty string*

If str2 CAN contain duplicate letters, then the list of positions (pos) needs to include multiple positions for repeated characters:

```
pos = [i for r in [list(str2)] for i,c in enumerate(str1) 
       if c in r and not r.remove(c)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` operations, for each prefix check that all letter are in with

```
set(str2) - set(str1[:1])

set(str2) - set('xB')       # {'C', 'A'}
set(str2) - set('xBxxA')    # {'C'}
set(str2) - set('xBxxAxxC') # set()
```

```
def myStr(str1, str2):
    chars_to_have = set(str2)
    i = 0
    while chars_to_have - set(str1[:i]) != set() and i < len(str1):
        i += 1
    return str1[:i]
```